# Crash of expo after the bundle load

Tags: react-native, crash, expo

I'm making a project in start expo is working properly .but when code some functions and imports file the expo goes crash after the load of bundle.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxWfK.png)
it show runtime crash. in error please help me in this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0GTs.png)

Comment: Please , add photo of error

Comment: after this i don't get any error and my expo close after that